# Display Country Flag in Profile Wordpress/Buddypress

Tags: user-meta

Hoping someone could help me with a question regarding displaying country flags next to a member name. Right now I am using a custom meta containing country and then echo the flag back  if the condition is met. Instead of writing out hundreds of lines of code to display a flag in this manner, is there a more efficient or smarter way of coding this. I can't imagine displaying 100's of lines of code in the members-header.php can be good.

Here is the code I am using to display the flag for Korea:

```
<?php

global $bp;

$korea = get_usermeta( $bp->displayed_user->id, 'location' );

if( $korea == 'korea' );

echo '<img src="http://www.mydomain.com/flags/KR.gif" border=0>';
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Tom

Comment: How is your user entering their country?  Free-text field, dropdown list, ...?

Comment: They are entering via a dropdown on registration. Gravity Forms then adds the custom meta to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to use those location values for something they were not intended for, so you need to convert the values somehow.

You can rename your `.gif`s to match the location value then you could do...

```
if( !empty($korea) ) {
    echo '<img src="http://www.mydomain.com/flags/'.$korea.'.gif" border=0>';
}
```

Please note the change I made to your code. You had `if( $korea == 'korea' );`. That `;` ended the line so your conditional did nothing. Your code is broken. That `img` always `echo`es. (And I added brackets. Bracket-less conditionals will trip you up.)

The other thing you could do is "map" the location value to a country. That is, build an array...

```
 $countries = array(
   'KR' => 'Korea',
   // ...
 }
```

Then use that to grab your `.gif`s.

```
function convert_location_wpse_99541($location) {
  $countries = array(
   'Korea' => 'KR',
   // ...
  }
  if (isset($counties[$location])) {
   return $counties[$location];
  }
}
// ...
$gif = convert_location_wpse_99541($korea)
if( !empty($gif) ) {
    echo '<img src="http://www.mydomain.com/flags/'.$gif.'.gif" border=0>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, this was what I was looking for, will have a go at implementing now.